# Merge Ubuntu and Windows partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

On my computer there are Windows and Ubuntu (the hard drive is divided).
Can I delete Windows and connect it hard disk space join Ubuntu? 
If "yes" => how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Just boot a live system (e.g. your installation medium), delete the windows partition and resize the Ubuntu partition. You can do this with GParted.

After that you might need to edit the /etc/fstab on your Ubuntu partition to set the new UUID of the resized partition - if it changes. You get all the UUIDs with `sudo blkid`

Then you can reboot and your Ubuntu should boot.